# Processing RDDs in a DStream in parallel

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I came across the following code which processes messages in Spark Streaming:

```
val listRDD = ssc.socketTextStream(host, port)
listRDD.foreachRDD(rdd => {
  rdd.foreachPartition(partition => {
    // Should I start a separate thread for each RDD and/or Partition?
    partition.foreach(message => {
      Processor.processMessage(message)
    })
  })
})
```

This is working for me but I am not sure if this is the best way. I understand that a DStream consists of "one to many" RDDs, but this code processes RDDs sequentially one after the other, right? Isn't there a better way - a method or function - that I can use so that all the RDDs in the DStream get processed in parallel? Should I start a separate thread for each RDD and/or Partition? Have I misunderstood how this code works under Spark?

Somehow I think this code is not taking advantage of the parallelism in Spark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Streams are partitioned in small RDDs for convenience and efficiency (check [micro-batching](https://www.google.cl/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=micro+batching). But you really don't need to break every RDD into partitions or even break the stream into RDDs.

It all depends on what `Processor.processMessage` really is. If it is a single transformation function, you can just do `listRDD.map(Processor.processMessage)` and you get a stream of whatever the result of processing a message is, computed in parallel with no need for you to do much else.

If `Processor` is a mutable object that holds state (say, counting the number of messages) then things are more complicated, as you will need to define many such objects to account for parallelism and will also need to somehow merge results later on.

Comment: After I changed this to 'listRDD.map(Processor.processMessage)' it stopped receiving messages. Do I have to use some other function call to 'activate'?

Comment: well, I still don't know what kind of function `processMessage` is, but going on a limb here. Did you assign the result of that to a variable and then did something with it (save it, print it, etc)?

Comment: for a quick debug (on few data), try adding `.print()` at the end of that statement.

Comment: The processMessage will 'extract' info from the message, transform it & save it. Each message is processed individually. It does not hold state. It is a single transformation function.

Comment: the 'save it' part might force you to use `foreachRDD` indeed. Spark is easier to use if you rely in the provided `save` functions. Check this: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#output-operations-on-dstreams

Comment: So then there's no better way to do this? The Processor.processMessage method does not use any Spark related code & it's not supposed to. We would like to keep it completely generic. It should take a 'Message' & do whatever we want without worrying about the underlying streaming technology. Today it's Spark Streaming, but tomorrow it could be 'Storm'. Somehow I still think this type of 'sequential' processing of RDDs is time consuming :(

Comment: Well, for a truly generic, reusable function (obviously without any Spark dependency) I would separate the part of `processMessage` that does "extract & transform" from the part that "saves". That helps you not only with independence of processing framework, but also from storage, etc. This is kind of what Spark expects (and Storm, both try to allow chaining of independent operations) and I was trying to show you.

Comment: That said, even if you use `mapPartitions` the computation is only "sequential" over a single partition. Multiple partitions are being executed in parallel in the same executor and over multiple executors in the cluster. That is why I was worried about state.